# NDK/JNI: identifying current thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk

In a JNI native method, is there a way to know the ID of the current thread without calling Java back? Thread-local storage would also work.

EDIT: pthread.h is present in the NDK include folder... Does anyone know if Java threads correspond to POSIX ones in the NDK implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which ID are you interested in?  A Dalvik thread dump includes this:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40017730 self=0x12798
  | sysTid=3167 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-2146114456
  | schedstat=( 358850000 275073000 869 ) utm=23 stm=12 core=0
```

"tid" is the VM's ID.
"handle" is the pthread_t.
"sysTid" is the result of gettid() (the Linux process ID).

The libcore thread ID (obtained from java.lang.Thread.getId()) is not shown.

(You can obtain the above with "adb shell kill -3 ".  The output goes to a common file, defined by the dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file property -- usually /data/anr/traces.txt, but it varies by device.)

**EDIT:** Every Dalvik VM thread is a Linux pthread.  The gettid() syscall will give you a unique ID for each thread.  Also, you can add identifying information to TLS in java.lang.Thread or pthread_key.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in having some actions that should not be performed on threads other than the main one. If(!(the currently executing JNI method is being called from a worker Java thread)){main thread only bits}.

Comment: The VM doesn't give the "main" thread any sort of preferential treatment.  You can get an approximation by checking to see if gettid() == getpid(), i.e. it's the main thread of a Linux process, but this is not guaranteed and could break in the future.  A better plan is to have the app UI thread set a value in thread-local storage (either java.lang.Thread or pthread TLS) and check that.

Comment: so java.lang.Threads *DO* correspond to pthreads? Thanks. Move that nugget of knowledge into your answer, and I'll accept. The ADB guidance is of zero relevance to me - I'm trying to do it this programmatically.