# Creating threads using the NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've been looking into writing a small cross-platform OpenGL/helper code that can compile on Android and the iPhone. I was looking up the best way to handle multiple threads within the NDK on Android and couldn't find a definitive answer. I read that fork() should not be used because Android doesn't keep tabs on those processes.

I'm not worried about making the forking cross-platform as it can be easily defined separately. So, I was wondering if anyone knew the best way to handle creation and management of multiple threads within the NDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [NDK/JNI: identifying current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749875/ndk-jni-identifying-current-thread) , Java threads on Android correspond to pthreads. So consider using those. The relevant C headers do come with NDK.

Not sure how will calling Java back from those threads work. I won't automatically assume that the JNI pointer is thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks! I had seen mention of pthreads but could not find that info anywhere